# Do there exist polynomials not computable in polynomial time?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, finite-fields, computational-complexity

Motivation: [Computing a problem in $k$ memory slots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756714/any-problem-computable-in-k-memory-slots-can-be-computed-with-polynomials/756800#756800)

Do there exist polynomials in $R = \Bbb{Z}_p[z_1, \dots, z_k]$ that can't be computed in time polynomial in $k,p$?

Thanks... Good luck!

*Edit*.  I think there may be irreducible polys in that ring that are hard to compute.  Or *something*!  Something is going on here, peeps.

Comment: I get computing *operations* on polynomials (like sums, products, sums of products, etc.), but what does it mean to compute a polynomial itself?

Comment: It seems your question is imprecise. How do you represent your polynomial? Does the size of the polynomial counts as well? What about the following series: $$P_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n [\text{the $n$-th Turing machine halts for all inputs}]x^k\quad ?$$

Comment: @dtldarek what are you saying with regards to that $P_n$ I don't know classical complexity theory well enough yet.  This is basically an algebraic approach.  You show that the ring model is suitable for your problem, then represent it with polynomials.  And any polynomial is of course a representable problem.

Comment: @EnjoysMath I'm asking if calculating series $P_n(x)$ is hard enough for you. It would help if you could explain what do you mean by "compute polynomials". For example, for any polynomial there exists an algorithm that just prints it out (so it's polynomial in size of the output, but still might not be polynomial in $k$ and $p$). On the other hand, if you specify the polynomial as a problem (e.g. given the input calculate a polynomial such that), then it might be arbitrarily hard (e.g. take any decision problem and output $x \to 1$ as "true" and $x \to 0$ as "false").

Comment: @dtldarek Computing polynomials, by that I mean evaluating them at any of the inputs, and taking the maximum running time of the algorithm that evaluates / computes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume that $p = 2$ and we are dealing with input in binary.

Let $F : \{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}$ be any boolean function. Define

\begin{align}
P(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1}) &= \sum_{a \in \{0,1\}^k} F(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1})\cdot\prod_{i = 0}^{k}\Big(a_ix_i+(1-a_i)(1-x_i)\Big) \\
&= \sum_{a \in \{0,1\}^k\ :\ F(a) = 1}\ \prod_{i = 0}^{k}\Big(a_ix_i+(1-a_i)(1-x_i)\Big).
\end{align}

Observe that $F \equiv P$, so any algorithm calculating $P$ at some input is also an algorithm for $F$ and vice versa. Now, there are $2^{2^k}$ different boolean functions and speaking informally, algorithms have to differ to represent all of them. In other words, there are functions such that for any algorithm there is an input that takes a lot of time to calculate. In fact, Shannon showed that most of them require [circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity) of size $\frac{2^{k}}{\log k}$, which isn't polynomial. You can find more info on circuit complexity [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~zwick/scribe-boolean.html).

Finally, be aware that there are deep connections between the circuit complexity and the standard time-complexity in terms of Turing machines, but these are nevertheless different concepts.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$