# Not every polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ can be factored, but can you do next best?

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity, computability

If $f \in R = \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ is irreducible or doesn't have many factors then it could be hard to compute?  *Possibly, I'm not saying, but...* any way, what if $f = h - g$ where $h, g$ are heavily "factored"?  Then in terms of computational complexity $f$ is now easy to compute.

Let $f$ be some irreducible.  Suppose there exist no $f = h + g$ such that $h, g$ are easy to compute.  Then $f$ is hard to compute.  Because if $f$ were easy to compute, then $f = h + g$ where $h$ is all the operations in memory to compute $f$ up to the last and $g$ equals the last operation.  Thus both $h, g$ are easy to compute and *contradiction*.

Thus I'm in search of an irreducible $f$ such that $f \neq h + g$ for any easy to compute $h, g$.

Now I think we need some sort of recursive definition using both $+, \cdot$.  This is a tough problem.  Any ideas??

Comment: What model of computation are you using?

Comment: @Bill See here for motivation: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756813/do-there-exist-polynomials-not-computable-in-polynomial-time

Comment: Any polynomial of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ can be evaluated for any input in $O(d)$ operations, whether factored or not, and it's known that no algorithm that works on arbitrary polynomials can beat $O(d)$ (though that can be improved if you want to calculate many values of the same polynomial); this is all in TAOCP vol. 4.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. One cannot talk rigorously about complexity without *precise* definitions. What are yours?

Comment: @BillDubuque if that's the case, you can't expect me to make a book-long post that no one will read.  But if you are interested then I will.

Comment: There are various models of computation used in this area (e.g. straight-line programs). It is impossible to infer which one you are using from what little you wrote.

Comment: @BillDubuque you're right this is ill-defined.  I will close.

Comment: No need to close, simply elaborate a bit.